# How use ShapeRenderer along with ScrollPane in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, rect, scene2d, scrollpane

Am currently making a game in **LibGDX** for Android. So far I have a **ScrollPane** with a table inside that contains a list with custom rows [AS SHOWN IN THE ATTACHED IMAGE]. I want each of those rows surrounded by a rectangle. Is it possible to achieve this?

These are the rows of the list

[image]

Comment: You don't want to be using ShapeRenderer to do this because you'll have to keep flushing both the SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer for every row. Create a NinePatchDrawable to be your stretchable rectangle to use as the background of the rows.

Comment: ohk, thanx will be lookin into that cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been viewed 100 times I might as well contribute even though it's almost 3 years old.

You can set debug on the child widget attached to the Scrollpane (which is probably a Table, so debugAll() or whatever you wish), which outlines the boundaries of the actors automatically.

This internally uses a Shaperenderer to do it from the Stage, and you can change the colour through the Table.debugTableColor, Table.debugCellColor, and Table.debugActorColor static fields.

Table.debugTableColor is for outlining the entire table, Table.debugCellColor is for each of the table's cells, and Table.debugActorColor is for the actors contained within each of the cells.

But yeah, this should only be used for debugging the layout.